# İmport external C/C++ DLL into Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, dll, dllimport

I want to integrate a service (RTI-DDS) for data communication into Unity. For this, I need to import many DLL's (written by C/C++) into Unity.

To do this, I copied the required DLLs into the Assets folder and added them to Visual Stuio as a reference.

No errors are detected when using DLL functions in Visual Studio. But I get a compile error in playmode:

```
All Compiler Errors Have To Be Fixed Before You Can Enter Playmode!
```

How can I successfully include all the necessary libraries in my project?

I reached [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html?_ga=2.164990847.1504241072.1589899556-552023857.1589185090) article while doing research about the problem.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class SomeScript : MonoBehaviour {
    ...

   [DllImport ("PluginName")]
   private static extern float FooPluginFunction ();
    ...
```

But this is not a solution to my problem. Because there are multiple libraries I want to use and importing them in this way seems very troublesome.
Moreover, I am not familiar with the source code of DLL's and I do not know which function belongs to which DLL.

Is there an easier way to do this?

**EDIT :**

The compiler error I received is exactly this:

```
Assets\Scripts\S2\ReadFile.cs(50,5): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DDS' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: you put it in the asset folder, did you make a plugins folder?

Comment: yes all DLLs are in Assets\Plugins directory

Comment: what are the listed compiler errors? you havent mentioned those..

Comment: Sorry for missing information, I added the necessary editing.

Comment: Id imagine their documentation and code examples would answer much of this